# Struggling to transition code from AppcompatActivity to Fragment. Unable to use setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, appcompatactivity

I'm trying to transition from using AppcomatActivity to Fragment, because I'm updating my app but I've run into a problem. I get a **"Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager" and "Unresolved reference: setSupportActionBar"**(That's all the Logcat shows me) when I try to run my app. Now I chose to switch to using fragments, because I also want to change the apps UI, usage is quicker than the previous version. Anyway here's my code:

**Recorder Fragment**

```
    package com.khumomashapa.notes.fragments

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
import com.khumomashapa.notes.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.toolbar3.*


class RecorderFragment : Fragment() {

    private var tabs: PagerSlidingTabStrip? = null
    private var pager: ViewPager? = null

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activity?.title = "Recorder";

        pager = pager?.findViewById<View>(R.id.pager) as ViewPager
        pager!!.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        tabs = tabs?.findViewById<View>(R.id.tabs) as PagerSlidingTabStrip
        tabs!!.setViewPager(pager)
        val toolbar = toolbar?.findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        toolbar.popupTheme = R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Light
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)




    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recorder, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    inner class MyAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?) : FragmentPagerAdapter(
        fm!!
    ) {
        private val titles = arrayOf(
            getString(R.string.tab_title_record),
            getString(R.string.tab_title_saved_recordings)
        )

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    return RecordFragment.newInstance(position)
                }
                1 -> {
                    return FileViewerFragment.newInstance(position)
                }
            }
            return null!!
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return titles.size
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return titles[position]

        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val LOG_TAG = RecorderFragment::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

The purpose of this class is to show a view pager that can switch between to other fragments I've already created. I was able to fix the other errors relating to this like the "Unresolved reference for findViewById" and the "MyAdapter class".

Comment: I fixed the reference problem, but now I'm receiving a Null pointer exception error for 'pager = pager!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.pager) as ViewPager'

Comment: This will always throw an exception, `pager` is null and you're asserting that it isn't with `!!`. You seem to be trying to find the `pager` inside itself which doesn't make any sense. You should be using `Activity.findViewById(int)`.

Comment: It work. All your answers worked. Thanks mate. I'll try and tag your comment as the right answer

Comment: onCreate does not have views yet in Fragment, so this is not going to work out of the box

Comment: The action bar started giving only after I applied your solutions. I'll try to change my title so it's easy for everyone to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `Fragment`, there are actually two relevant fragment managers. Deciding which one to use depends on your use case.

### The Child Fragment Manager

A fragment has a child fragment manager which is responsible for managing its child/nested fragments. You can obtain this with:

```
Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()
```

### The Parent's Fragment Manager

A fragment also holds reference to it's parent's fragment manager. If the fragment is a direct child of an activity then his represents the activities fragment manager. Otherwise if the fragment is a child of another fragment, it represents the child fragment manager of the parent fragment. This can be obtained with:

```
Fragment.getParentFragmentManager()
```

---

Note that although `Fragment` has the method [`Fragment.getFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getFragmentManager()), this is deprecated in favour of `Fragment.getParentFragmentManager()` so it shouldn't be used.

You can also technically get the activities fragment manager regardless by obtaining a reference to the fragment's activity with `Fragment.getAcitivity()` and then calling `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager()`. But generally the parent fragment manager is more useful and clear.

Comment: I'm just going to ask a new question, because my problem is not related to this anymore.

Comment: I'll have to ask another question again. It would be a bit confusing to add it to this one.